# Git to a Web-server : How To Set remote git server to automatically merge the branch after pushing?

Tags: git

First of all, im new to Git and Git hooks. Here's what im trying to do... I want to create a local git repository where I'll work on my website. Then, I want to setup a git repository in my webserver and push the changes directly from my machine to the server using git. For this, what is the best path?

- I followed some online guides and did this...
- Initiated a repository on the remote server.
- Initiated a repository on my local machine
- Made a commit
- Switched to a different branch (Can't push the master branch to the server (If I can, its a lot easy))
- Pushed that branch to the server
- Logged into the server and merged the branch into the master from within it

My questions are,
Is this the best way to do the job?
If it is, can I do the merging part using hooks automatically? (How to do it? Im new to hooks)

Comment: Just curious, any specific reason you can't push to the master? Reading from your question - looks like it's your own server? By the way - what you needs is a post-commit hook: http://git-scm.com/book/mk/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks - they are simple shell scripts.

Comment: @xk0der When pushing to the master branch, it gave me this error : refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading your question and the comment - the problem is with the way you initialized the repository on your server.

On your server you need to initialize a **bare** repository, using the following command:

```
git init --bare
```

That will fix the error you got when pushing to the server.

Comment: I managed to push the changes, but in the remote directory, I can't see the changes... instead, I see the following files and folders (with the ls command) : branches  config  description  HEAD  hooks  info  objects  refs  (Because im working with a webserver, I need those files to be present in the remote directory )  PS : Thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: bare repositories do not have working-tree/work-folder/workspace - hence the name `bare`, they only contain the content which normally would reside inside the `.git` folder of a normal repo. If you want to check whether the server indeed got the changes pushed - you may clone the _repo_ in a different folder and check the files and folder.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are really trying to do - But I think if you clone the repo from your _client_ on the _server_ - you'll get what you want.

Comment: Cloning it to another directory in the same server? Then each time I push changes to the main repo (the bare one), i need to update the cloned one separately?

Comment: No - you have a repo on your client - which you also want on your server - so instead of initializing a repo on server and pushing to it - just clone the repo on your server (from the client) .

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15805/discussion-between-xk0der-and-eapubs)